# What is the meaning of "Shulamit"?

Tags: shir-hashirim

*Shir Hashirim* - Song of Songs 7:1 uses the word "Shulamit". Is this the name of a person or place?

Comment: −1 because you give no indication of why you think it's one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ibn Ezra (in his First Time, where he discusses the literal definitions), Isaiah di Trani, and Saadiah Gaon say that a Shulamit is someone from Shalem, which is Jerusalem.

Rashbam takes it to be from the root של״מ, meaning whole, perfect, and so translates "the perfect one".

H. J. Mathews' Unknown Commentary on the Song of Songs says that Shulamit means beloved of Shlomo (or alternatively, the same "perfect" translation as Rashbam).

Answer (score 2):

[Devar Yerushalayim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47133&st=&pgnum=84&hilite=) says that Shulamis is the Jewish nation which is complete in its faith of Hashem.